# How to change location of search bar top page in website? also how to costumize the search box?

Tags: sharepoint-online

i want the search box to only search and display values from first column in lists, my website mainly contain just lists and i want the search box to search throught first column which is for cosutmer names and when someone search for specified name search bar shows list of names

Answer (score 0):

The list search box cannot be customized. If it is the title column, modern list search box will display the title column entries.
[image]

You can try the format: `list Intenal Name: value`

Comment: can you show me step by step please thanks in advance